# Is it possible to create an Azure Storage Event Grid Subscription to an Azure Function deployment slot?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid, azure-deployment-slots

I'm using Azure Portal to create a new Event Grid Subscription on my Blob Storage account.

When configuring the "**Endpoint Details**" section, I specify that the Endpoint Type is an Azure Function. When prompted to select the Function I want to subscribe to, I'm unable to specify which Deployment Slot the Function is in.

The only item available in the Slot dropdown is "Production". But I've verified that the Function contains more than just that one default Slot. The info icon reveals the following:

[image: "Preview supports production slot only"]

I understood this to be a limitation of Azure Portal and attempted to circumvent the issue by opening the Advanced Editor and manually modifying the Resource ID to include the path to the Slot.

Portal-generated Resource ID:
`"/subscriptions/[subscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[groupName]/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/[functionAppName]/functions/[functionName]"`

Manually edited Resource ID:
`"/subscriptions/[subscriptionId]/resourceGroups/[groupName]/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/[functionAppName]/slots/[slotName]/functions/[functionName]"`

Then I attempt to create the Subscription and get the following error:

[image: "Invalid ARM Id"]

Is it possible to create an Azure Storage Event Grid Subscription to an Azure Function deployment slot? I cannot find any resources which explain how to accomplish this using Portal, PowerShell, CLI, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I know and as per the Microsoft Documentation Event Grid is still in preview mode for Azure functions and it is not fully supported.
- Here is the [Feedback form](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/a095b5b5-f124-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) for raising a Feature Request.

[image]

[image]

- Here is the Github [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/2184#issuecomment-674344542) for further investigation.